# Topic modelling using LDA

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp

While defining corpus and dictionary for building the LDA model by defining topics how can we different topics keywords

It is working while giving an explicitly topic number, but I want that to be iterated.

## Preparing dictionary and corpus

```
from gensim import corpora

dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(doc_clean)

corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in doc_clean]
```

## Building LDA Model

```
lda_model = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus = corpus , id2word=dictionary , num_topics=10 , random_state=100, update_every=1 , chunksize=100 , passes=10 , alpha='auto' , per_word_topics=True)
```

## Printing the Keywords in topics

```
topics = print(lda_model.print_topic(6))

doc_lda = lda_model[corpus]
```

I want to know how can we iterate the topics instead of giving manually each time topic number

Comment: you can simply do a `for loop` on `num_topics`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Rahul. I am new to the topic modeling and coding stuff. I have already defined number_topics as 10 so when i am trying to loop in from topics it is throwing an error.

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking for [print_topics](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html#gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel.print_topics), but it's not clear. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Lomtrur, yeah you are right if you see the below code i have given print_topic(6). I have ten such topics. But problem here is every time i need to change the topic numer in print_topic(). Instead i want to display all 10 topics output as below.    O/P : 0.030*"cell" + 0.015*"hypertrophy" + 0.008*"type" + 0.008*"3" + 0.008*"mediate" + 0.008*"human" + 0.008*"integration" + 0.008*"singlecell" + 0.008*"early" + 0.008*"crest"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your ask correctly, all you need is:

```
topics = []
num_topics=10
for i in range((num_topics)):
    topics.append(lda_model.print_topic(i+1))
```